# How do I configure S3 access for org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetReader?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, parquet

I struggled with this for a while and wanted to share my solution. AvroParquetReader is a fine tool for reading Parquet, but its defaults for S3 access are weak:

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: doesBucketExist on MY_BUCKET: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider SharedInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

I want to use credentials providers akin to those used by com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider, which works for accessing my S3 bucket, but it is not clear from AvroParquetReader's class definition or documentation how I would achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me. It allowed AvroParquetReader to access S3 using ProfileCredentialsProvider.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetReader;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

...

final String path = "s3a://"+bucketName+"/"+pathName;
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setClass("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", ProfileCredentialsProvider.class,
        AWSCredentialsProvider.class);
ParquetReader<GenericRecord> parquetReader =
        AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(new Path(path)).withConf(configuration).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else experiencing problems with this I found that @jd_free answer didn't work for me. The only thing I needed to change for this to work was the configuration settings passed to `AvroParquetReader` regarding the kind of `AWSCredentialsProvider` used:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider");
        configuration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "KEY");
        configuration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "KEY");`
```

The problem was the credentials provider given, and the way it was given to the configuration. For more information on the different credential providers you can use check out [this page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Changing_Authentication_Providers). It explains the different kinds you can use for different scenarios, including how to grab credentials from your environment variables.