# How to read parquet file from S3 using akka streams or alpakka

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, parquet, akka-stream, alpakka

Im trying to read parque file from S3 using akka streams following [the official doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/avroparquet.html#source-initiation) but I am getting this error
`java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3a`
this is the code that triggered that exception. I will highly appreciate any clue/example of how should I do it correctly

```
val path = s"s3a://bucketName/path/to/foo/part-00000-656418ee-7cc0-42ee-93e-aaa69ee6f916.c000.snappy.parquet"
val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
conf.setBoolean(AvroReadSupport.AVRO_COMPATIBILITY, true)
val file = HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path(path), conf)
val reader: ParquetReader[GenericRecord] =
    AvroParquetReader.builder[GenericRecord](file).withConf(conf).build()
    //should read the file lines here but not there yet ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely missing `hadoop-aws` lib on your classpath.

Have a look here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

And also this SO gives some more details how to setup credentials for access to S3:
[How do I configure S3 access for org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524156/how-do-i-configure-s3-access-for-org-apache-parquet-avro-avroparquetreader)

Once you have `AvroParquetReader` correctly initialized, then you can create Akka Stream's `Source` out of it as per the Alpakka Avro Parquet doc (https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/avroparquet.html#source-initiation)